# ASP.NET Core UrlHelper customize parameters serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to build url to the action in ASP.NET Core. There is handy way to do this - use `IUrlHelper` interface, which is accessible in any controller through `Url` property. Unfortunally, `UrlHelper` use `ToString()` method for parameter serialization and I don't know how to customize serialization for specific types. This leads to the problems with custom types in request models:

```
public class ComplexFilter {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return $"[A = {A}, B = {B}]";
    }
}
public class WebRequest {
    [FromRoute]
    public string Id { get;set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public ComplexFilter Filter { get;set; }
}
```

I want to use `WebRequest` class as a parameter of my controller action with url structure like this `search/{id}?filter=A-B`:

```
[HttpGet("search/{id}")]
public ActionResult Search(WebRequest request) {
    return Ok();
}
```

I don't want to override `ToString()` method of my `ComplexFilter`, because it is used in another parts of the application and has more friendly format for logging and debugging.
In this situation there is two problems:

1. I need to deserialize `ComplexFilter` from request. This can be done with the help of `TypeDescriptor`: `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(ComplexFilter), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ComplexFilterTypeConverter)));`
2. I need to serialize `ComplexFilter` for link generation. If I simply call `Url.Action("Search", new WebRequest { Id = "id", Filter = new ComplexFilter { A = "A", B = "B" } })`, then I get following url: `/action/id?filter=[A = \"A\", B = \"B\"]`, but I want to get `/action/id?filter=A-B`.

So my question is - how can I customize UrlBuilder parameter serialization behaviour, to add custom serialization logic for `CustomFilter` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `UrlHelper` (implementing `IUrlHelper`) will convert your values object to a list of key-value pairs in which `ToString()` will be used to convert the property values. I doubt that internally it will use `RouteValueDictionary` to convert the values object before delegating the link generation to some internal `LinkGenerator` (a new concept used in `asp.net core`). I did not refer to the source code so that's just guessing. Basically there is no other point to make it not use `ToString()` and instead use some other one to resolve the property values. So you can just rely on a custom `UrlHelper`.

The following solution requires you to do 2 things:

- Convert the values object to an `IDictionary<string,string>` in which you use a method of your choice to convert the property value instead of using the default `ToString()`.
- Create a custom `UrlHelper` to override the `Action` method to apply the custom conversion above before calling the base method. This is optional for convenience. Otherwise you need to call a method to apply the conversion above before passing it to the default `UrlHelper.Action`.

To help recognize what type supports a custom method to generate a string value in the logic you want, you can define a specific interface which must be implemented by that type. I name that interface `ILinkGeneratedString`. Here is the full code:

```
public interface ILinkGeneratedString
{
    string LinkGeneratedString { get; }
}

//an extension method used to convert property value to a string
public static class UrlValuesExtensions
{
    public static object ToUrlValues(this object o)
    {
        if (o == null || o is RouteValueDictionary) return o;
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //only public readable properties are read
        //this excludes the indexers (a special type of property) as well
        foreach(var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties()
                                       .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0))
        {
            var pv = prop.GetValue(o);
            var value = pv == null ? "" :
                        pv is ILinkGeneratedString ls ? ls.LinkGeneratedString : pv.ToString();
            values[prop.Name] = value;
        }
        return values;
    }
}

//the custom UrlHelper
public class CustomUrlHelper : UrlHelper
{
    public CustomUrlHelper(ActionContext actionContext) : base(actionContext)
    {
    }
    public override string Action(UrlActionContext actionContext)
    {            
        //apply the conversion here
        actionContext.Values = actionContext?.Values?.ToUrlValues();
        return base.Action(actionContext);
    }
}

//we need a custom IUrlHelperFactory as well
public class CustomUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory
{
    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
    {
        return new CustomUrlHelper(context);
    }
}
```

Now in the `Startup.ConfigureServices`, you need to register the custom `IUrlHelperFactory` like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, CustomUrlHelperFactory>();
```

To use a custom `ToString()` for your `ComplexFilter` to use for link generation, you need to implement `ILinkGeneratedString` (as I've mentioned before) like this:

```
public class ComplexFilter : ILinkGeneratedString {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
      return $"[A = {A}, B = {B}]";
    }
    public string LinkGeneratedString => $"{A}-{B}";
}
```

For any other types which need similar custom link generation like that, you just implement that `ILinkGeneratedString`. It's so convenient that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to use more simpler approach and introduce `facade` dto - `WebComplexFilter` which has necessary `ToString()` operator and pair of implict cast operators for conversion from/to `ComplexFilter`.

Comment: Also, I am very surprised, that `ASP NET Core` provides no way to externally configure serialization behaviour in this situation.

Comment: you're welcome, I think the approach I introduced here is basically how you can extend it. The default implementation uses `ToString` but that one is not usable in your case, so you need another method for that (the `LinkGeneratedString` as in my implementation). After adding a custom UrlHelper like this, it works just like the default UrlHelper but with more logic to handle any interface exposed via the route value.